# scheduling file every 1 hour using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to run a print statement every 1 hour in Windows environment using node.js. I use the package node-schedule.

But when I tried running this, the output is not as expected. I think my schedule format is wrong.

So I tried the following code:

```js
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * *', function(){
    console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

Answer (score 10):

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* 1 * * *', function(){  // this for one hour
console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

> The cron format consists of:
>
> ```
> *    *    *    *    *    *
> ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
> │    │    │    │    │    |
> │    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
> │    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
> │    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
> │    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
> │    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
> └───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
> ```

Here is the link: https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule

Comment: i haven't tested this, but this might be wrong? the "second" field is "OPTIONAL". If you include the "second" field, that's 6 parameters. You only included five, so that "1" parameter is filling in the space for "day of month".

Comment: this won't schedule every hour. it'll just run at the 1st day of the month. but thanks for the diagram.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const job = schedule.scheduleJob('1 * * * *', () => { // run every hour at minute 1
    console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

More examples:

- Every 2 minutes: `*/2 * * * *`
- Every 2 hours when at 5 minute mark: `5 */2 * * *`

You should use this friendly [tool](https://crontab.guru/#5_*/2_*_*_*) to read and verify the config. Example:

[image]

It's worth noting that not all cronjob libs support the same fine-grain time level. For example:

- Linux crontab: at the minute level (allow 5 * in the config)
- node-schedule: at the second level (allow 6 * in the config)

Answer (score 4):

Why can't you use setInerval()

```
setInterval(function () {
   console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
}, 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 1 hour
```

Comment: Don't mean to necro, but the `setInterval` function only runs from when the script was started. Using the `schedule.scheduleJob` function is better because you can control exactly when it runs.

Answer (score 1):

This will run every 1 hour, 0th minute, 0th second( ex: execute at 1PM, 2PM, 3PM etc):

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('0 0 */1 * * *', function() {
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
job.start();
```

Refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Answer (score 0):

This will run by based on your time zone, for example, Now the time in your time is 12:30, your scheduler will run by 01:00.Please check

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more "*" to the cron-style.
They do have a good [README.md](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule) if you want to find out more about it.

```js
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

const job = schedule.scheduleJob('* */1 * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

The [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) format consists of:

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    |
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

**EDIT**

If you would like to run it once every hour on a specific minute, you can also do this and switch the 0 with any minute 0-59:

```js
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

const job = schedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This runs when **"second is zero"** and **"minute is zero"**, and "any hour", "any day", "any month", "any day-of-week". Basically, every hour.

```
schedule.scheduleJob("0 0 * * * *", function() {
   console.log('I run every hour');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will run every hour at 0 min, 0 secs.

```
const job = schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 */1 * * *', function(fireDate){
  console.log('This job was supposed to run at ' + fireDate + ', but actually ran at ' + new Date());
});
```